# How does copy-on-write work in fork()?

Tags: c, linux, unix, fork, copy-on-write

I want to know how copy-on-write happens in fork().

Assuming we have a process A that has a dynamical int array:

```
int *array = malloc(1000000*sizeof(int));
```

Elements in array are initialized to some meaningful values.
Then, we use fork() to create a child process, namely B.
B will iterate the array and do some calculations:

```
for(a in array){
    a = a+1;
}
```

1. I know B will not copy the entire array immediately, but when does the child B allocate memory for array? during fork()?
2. Does it allocate the entire array all at once, or only a single integer for `a = a+1`?
3. `a = a+1;` how does this happen? Does B read data from A and write new data to its own array?

I wrote some code to explore how COW works. My environment: ubuntu 14.04, gcc4.8.2

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>

void printMemStat(){
    struct sysinfo si;
    sysinfo(&si);
    printf("===\n");
    printf("Total: %llu\n", si.totalram);
    printf("Free: %llu\n", si.freeram);
}

int main(){
    long len = 200000000;
    long *array = malloc(len*sizeof(long));
    long i = 0;
    for(; i<len; i++){
        array[i] = i;
    }

    printMemStat();
    if(fork()==0){
        /*child*/
        printMemStat();

        i = 0;
        for(; i<len/2; i++){
            array[i] = i+1;
        }

        printMemStat();

        i = 0;
        for(; i<len; i++){
            array[i] = i+1;
        }

        printMemStat();

    }else{
        /*parent*/
        int times=10;
        while(times-- > 0){
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After fork(), the child process modifies a half of numbers in array, and then modifies the entire array. The outputs are:

```
===
Total: 16694571008
Free: 2129162240
===
Total: 16694571008
Free: 2126106624
===
Total: 16694571008
Free: 1325101056
===
Total: 16694571008
Free: 533794816
```

It seems that the array is not allocated as a whole. If I slightly change the first modification phase to:

```
i = 0;
for(; i<len/2; i++){
    array[i*2] = i+1;
}
```

The outputs will be:

```
===
Total: 16694571008
Free: 2129924096
===
Total: 16694571008
Free: 2126868480
===
Total: 16694571008
Free: 526987264
===
Total: 16694571008
Free: 526987264
```

Comment: The child doesn't "allocate" anything. The child starts out as an exact, complete copy of the parent process and just continues executing from there.

Comment: So, A and B share the array?

Comment: @KerrekSB: But it will get its own separate process memory, which should be copy-on-write.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613566/fork-and-copy-on-write

Comment: COW is an implementation detail, it doesn't affect your program. This question would probably be better for unix.stackexchange.com or superuser.com.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depends on the Operating System, hardware architecture and libc. But yes in case of recent Linux with MMU the [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) will work with copy-on-write. It will only (allocate and) copy a few system structures and the page table, but the heap pages actually point to the ones of the parent until written.

More control over this can be exercised with the [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) call. And [vfork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vfork.2.html) beeing a special variant which does not expect the pages to be used. This is typically used before exec().

As for the allocation: the malloc() has meta information over requested memory blocks (address and size) and the C variable is a pointer (both in process memory heap and stacks). Those two look the same for the child (same values because same underlying memory page seen in the address space of both processes). So from a C program point of view the array is already allocated and the variable initialized when the process comes into existence. The underlying memory pages are however pointing to the original physical ones of the parent process, so no extra memory pages are needed until they are modified.

If the child allocates a new array it depends if it fits into the already existing heap pages or if the brk of the process needs to be increased. In both cases only the modified pages get copied and the new pages get allocated only for the child.

This also means that the physical memory might run out after malloc(). (Which is bad as the program cannot check the error return code of "a operation in a random code line"). Some operating systems will not allow this form of overcommit: So if you fork a process it will not allocate the pages, but it requires them to be available at that moment (kind of reserves them) just in case. In Linux this is [configurable and called overcommit-accounting](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting).

Comment: But when will the child process allocate memory for array? (only allocate memory not copy)

Comment: @MinFu Depends on what you mean with "memory" and "allocate" :) (I added some additonal explanation to the answer).

Comment: What happens if the child detaches it from the parent? I guess all pages of parent gets copied to child space before the child gets detached. If not, what happens when the parent dies/exists after the fork?

Comment: A page shared between multiple processes has no owner, the pages do not have to be copied on detach. The page is alive as long as it is mapped to any process.

Comment: For those like me who didn't know what [brk](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/brk.2.html) means: it's the end of the data section of the program. Increasing it effectively allocates more memory to the process.

Answer (score 5):

**Some systems have a system call `vfork()`, which was originally
designed as a lower-overhead version of `fork()`. Since
`fork()` involved copying the entire address space of the process,
and was therefore quite expensive, the `vfork()` function was
introduced (in 3.0BSD).**

However, since `vfork()` was introduced, the
implementation of `fork()` has improved drastically, most notably
with the introduction of 'copy-on-write', **where the copying of the
process address space is transparently faked by allowing both processes
to refer to the same physical memory until either of them modify
it.** This largely removes the justification for `vfork();` indeed, a
large proportion of systems now lack the original functionality of
`vfork()` completely. For compatibility, though, there may still be
a `vfork()` call present, that simply calls `fork()` without
attempting to emulate all of the `vfork()` semantics.

As a result, it is very unwise to actually make use of any of the
differences between `fork()` and `vfork()`. Indeed, it is
probably unwise to use `vfork()` at all, unless you know exactly
why you want to.

**The basic difference between the two is that when a new process is created with `vfork()`, the parent process is temporarily suspended, and the child process might borrow the parent's address space. This strange state of affairs continues until the child process either exits, or calls `execve()`, at which point the parent process continues.**

This means that the child process of a `vfork()` must be careful to
avoid unexpectedly modifying variables of the parent process. In
particular, the child process must not return from the function
containing the `vfork()` call, and it must not call
`exit()` (if it needs to exit, it should use `_exit();`
actually, this is also true for the child of a normal `fork()`).