# What happens to allocated memory of other threads when forking

Tags: linux, exec, fork

I have a huge application that needs to fork itself at some point. The application is multithreaded and has about 200MB of allocated memory. What I want to do now to ensure that the data allocated by the process wont get duplicated is to start a new thread and fork inside of this thread. From what I have read, only the thread that calls `fork` will be duplicated, but what will happen to the allocated memory? Will that still be there? The purpose of this is to restart the application with other startup parameters, when its forked, it will call `main` with my new parameters, thus getting hopefully a new process of the same program. Now before you ask: I cannot assure that the binary of that process will still be in the same place as when I started the process, otherwise I could just `fork` and `exec` whats in `/proc/self/exe`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27161412/how-does-copy-on-write-work-in-fork

Answer (score 0):

Threads are execution units inside the big bag of resources that a process is. A process is the whole thing that you can access from any thread in the process: all the threads, all the file descriptors, all the other resources. So memory is absolutely not tied to a thread, and forking from a thread has no useful effect. *Everything* still needs to be copied over since the point of forking is creating a new process.

That said, Linux has some tricks to make it faster. Copying 2 gigabytes worth of RAM is neither fast or efficient. So when you fork, Linux actually gives the new process the *same* memory (at first), but it uses the virtual memory system to mark it as copy-on-write: as soon as one process needs to write to that memory, the kernel intercepts it and allocates distinct memory so that the other process isn't affected.