# How to determine whether a Linux version supports copy-on-write fork()

Tags: linux

I am currently developing a python script that uses the multiprocessing module (more specifically, multiprocessing.Pool) to split the workload of populating some files with data held within large (several GBs) data structures in memory. At first I was concerned that scaling this up would be a problem if processes copy the entire process state (including the large data structures) across to each sub-process after forking the main process. However, reading up on how to reduce this memory footprint led me to the information that [recent versions of Linux support copy-on-write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27161457/1506086) when forking a process, meaning that the total physical memory footprint is significantly reduced.

However, I am unsure whether the version of Linux that I am using is sufficiently recent to have this functionality. Is there a relatively simple way I can find out?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's been this way for well over 20 years...

Comment: Thanks, my feeling was that that was probably the case but I'm struggling to find any specific information on it.

Comment: I know 2.0 kernels in the mid/late 90's used COW pages. Not sure about 0.X or 1.X... before my time.